# What causes a view to be empty in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created a view for my assignment and added in all of the necessary data I need to display however I don't understand what would make it not display anything. I am really new to SQL so don't laugh at me.

This is the view:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Ticket_T.ticketID, dbo.Ticket_T.assignedDate, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketPriority, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketETA, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketFlag, dbo.Ticket_T.userID, dbo.Ticket_T.staffID, 
                         dbo.User_T.userID AS Expr1, dbo.Staff_T.staffID AS Expr2, dbo.Staff_T.staffName, dbo.User_T.categoryType, dbo.User_T.userDate, dbo.User_T.userDescription, dbo.User_T.userName, dbo.Status_T.ticketStatus AS Expr3, 
                         dbo.Staff_T.staffRole
FROM            dbo.Ticket_T INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Status_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus = dbo.Status_T.ticketStatus INNER JOIN
                         dbo.User_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.userID = dbo.User_T.userID INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Staff_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.staffID = dbo.Staff_T.staffID
ORDER BY dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus
```

Context: Its a ticketing help desk system and I  am  trying to create a view that shows  me the tickets in order  of status (Completed/Incomplete)

Comment: lots of ways to debug - i usually start selecting from my first join to my nth join to see where the issue is then start changing the behavior of the joins.

Comment: Why do you specify the issue is with the view? When running the query directly (no view involved) it works fine? (it should behave the same, of course).

Comment: Side note, remove the `TOP` and `ORDER BY` clauses from the view as it serves no purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to perform a select from your view

```
SELECT V.* FROM YourView AS V
```

Comment: Yes I have, It comes back with all empty results

Comment: Then I would do the following:  in your code replace inner join with left join to see where records are dissappeared

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much, would you mind explaining to me why it worked?

Comment: Sure :-)  The INNER JOIN keyword selects records that have matching values in both tables, E.g if you haven't got dbo.Staff_T.staffID which matches the value of dbo.Ticket_T.staffID,such record will be discarded. In case of LEFT JOIN dbo.Staff_T.staffID AS Expr2 will be NULL

Answer (score 0):

The view would return no rows if any of the joins fail -- this would usually be because one of the tables is empty or you are using the wrong `join` keys.

Also, the `order by` is not appropriate in the view.  You should remove both it and the `top (100) percent`.

Comment: Okay so I am very new to this, could you explain the best way for  me to debug this would be please? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If you will be using an INNER JOIN then make sure that the value exists on the column of both left and right tables. Let take for example the first join that you have

```
dbo.Ticket_T INNER JOIN
    dbo.Status_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus = dbo.Status_T.ticketStatus
```

Let's say the **ticketStatus** in table **Ticket_T** is **Sold** then there must also be this same **ticketStatus** value in table **Status_T** in order for the joined rows to appear.

If you still want to proceed with the join even if there is no matching value in both tables then you can replace the **INNER JOIN** with a **LEFT OUTER JOIN**.

> Left Outer Join: Returns all the rows from the LEFT table and matching records between both the tables.

And have your query like this:

```
SELECT    TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Ticket_T.ticketID, dbo.Ticket_T.assignedDate, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketPriority, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketETA, dbo.Ticket_T.ticketFlag, dbo.Ticket_T.userID, dbo.Ticket_T.staffID, 
           dbo.User_T.userID AS Expr1, dbo.Staff_T.staffID AS Expr2, dbo.Staff_T.staffName, dbo.User_T.categoryType, dbo.User_T.userDate, dbo.User_T.userDescription, dbo.User_T.userName, dbo.Status_T.ticketStatus AS Expr3, 
           dbo.Staff_T.staffRole
FROM     dbo.Ticket_T LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Status_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus = dbo.Status_T.ticketStatus LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.User_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.userID = dbo.User_T.userID LEFT OUTER JOIN
         dbo.Staff_T ON dbo.Ticket_T.staffID = dbo.Staff_T.staffID
ORDER BY dbo.Ticket_T.ticketStatus
```